# Sage CRM - See the name of the screens used in a tab?

Tags: tabs, screens, sage-crm

As the title says, if i want to know the name of screens to then know what screen to customize, how do i know it?

For example, if i go to a Company and im in the tab Summary, how do i know what screens/blocks etc im seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to go to:
Administration -> Customisation -> (any entity) -> Screens
The tick the "Inline Customisation" tickbox, just below the tabs:

[image: Sage CRM - Inline Customisation - Six Ticks Limited]

Then, go back to the Main Menu and go to any Company record. You will see the inline customisation options at the top of each screen:

[image: Sage CRM - Customise Screen - Six Ticks Limited]

Click the "Customise Screen" link and a pop-up will appear (make sure you don't have a pop-up blocker).
At the top of that pop-up, it will tell you the Screen name:

[image: Sage CRM - Screen Customisation Pop-up - Six Ticks Limited]

You can either customise the screen from this pop-up, or go back into the Administration section, find the screen, and customise it from there.

I hope that helps!

Six Ticks Limited

Comment: Ty, i just noticed that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just activate the "Integrated personalization" in Admin > Personalization > ENTITY > Screens > And then check the "Integrated personalization"

This way, a link will appear at top of every screen and it will let you customize that speceific screen